# Is my borrow checker drunk?

Tags: rust

> reference must be valid for the block at 50:74...
>   ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 50:74

Right. So what's the problem?

The block in question:

```
pub fn git_upload_pack(self: &mut GitConnect) -> Result<String, &str> {
    let c = format!("git-upload-pack {}\0host={}\0", self.repo.path, self.repo.domain);

    let mut out = String::new();
    let data = try!(self.command(c.as_slice()));

    for line in data.iter() {
        out.push_str(from_utf8(line.as_slice()).unwrap());
    }

    Ok(out)
}
```

`self.command`:

```
fn command(self: &mut GitConnect, command: &str) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, &str> {
```

The full error:

```
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:54:38: 54:39 error: `c` does not live long enough
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:54         let data = try!(self.command(c.as_slice()));
                                                                    ^
<std macros>:1:1: 6:60 note: in expansion of try!
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:54:20: 54:53 note: expansion site
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:50:75: 61:6 note: reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 50:74...
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:50     pub fn git_upload_pack(self: &mut GitConnect) -> Result<String, &str> {
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:51         let c = format!("git-upload-pack {}\0host={}\0", self.repo.path, self.repo.domain);
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:52 
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:53         let mut out = String::new();
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:54         let data = try!(self.command(c.as_slice()));
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:55 
                               ...
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:50:75: 61:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 50:74
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:50     pub fn git_upload_pack(self: &mut GitConnect) -> Result<String, &str> {
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:51         let c = format!("git-upload-pack {}\0host={}\0", self.repo.path, self.repo.domain);
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:52 
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:53         let mut out = String::new();
src/protocol/git_connect.rs:54         let data = try!(self.command(c.as_slice()));
```

Comment: What's the signature of `self.command`?

Comment: Also could you please provide the full code of your function, including its signature? It may be important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me.

This signature:

```
fn command(self: &mut GitConnect, command: &str) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, &str>
```

according to [lifetime elision rules](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0141-lifetime-elision.md#the-rules), should be equivalent to this one:

```
fn command<'a, 'b>(self: &'a mut GitConnect, command: &'b str) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, &'a str>
```

And in fact if you rewrite your `command()` to use this expanded variant it should compile. Also if you use shorthand `self` argument definition:

```
fn command(&mut self, command: &str) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, &str>
```

then it also compiles.

It seems that currently

```
fn command(self: &mut GitConnect, command: &str) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, &str>
```

is equivalent to

```
fn command<'a>(self: &'a mut GitConnect, command: &'a str) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, &'a str>
```

which gives exactly the same error for the correct reason because there is a lifetime error: `command` parameter's lifetime is asserted to be the same as `self`, so it won't work with local variables whose lifetime will be shorter than the one of `self`.

Comment: I figured it out just before you posted - you're almost right, except the lifetime of the `Result` `&str` is unrelated to the lifetime of the input. Specifically, it's `&'static str`. Looks like it was giving the `Result` `&str` the same lifetime as the `command` parameter

Comment: Well, according to your signatures and elision rules it *is* related to the input.

Comment: FWIW, I've submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21400).